# Nginx : Location = / not working with location /

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx host file with two locations and I want to have the exact / goes to index.html
and /something goes to my proxy.

I have a landing page in HTML that I want to use for my_domain.com and my React App is served in a proxy pass, so I want that my_domain.com/something point to my proxy (react app).

*something used above can be any string*

I've tried this but it's not working it's always redirecting to my second location :

```
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location = / {
    root /var/www/domain;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3020;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `location /user {` on the second block ?

Comment: You need to enable the debug mode of nginX (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/debugging/) - it will show you the exact reason why your requests are being redirected.

Comment: You are using `try_files` incorrectly. Use: `try_files /index.html =404;`